# yii 1.x.x Tabular input

Tags: input, yii, tabular

i have a _form view with tabular input as below:

```
Aspect1  
                     city1                    city2                   city3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. cond1.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as k1] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k1] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k1]
2. cond1.2  [dropwown(1,2,3) as k2] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k2] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k2]
3. cond1.3  [dropwown(1,2,3) as k3] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k3] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k3]

4. cond2.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as k4] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k4] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k4]
5. cond2.2  [dropwown(1,2,3) as k5] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k5] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k5]

6. cond3.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as k6] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k6] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k6]
7. cond3.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as k7] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k7] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as k7]

Aspect2  
                     city1                    city2                   city3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. cond1.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as e1] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as e1] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as e1]
2. cond1.2  [dropwown(1,2,3) as e2] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as e2] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as e2]
3. cond1.3  [dropwown(1,2,3) as e3] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as e3] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as e3]

4. cond2.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as e4] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as ke] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as e4]
5. cond2.2  [dropwown(1,2,3) as e5] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as ke] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as e5]

Aspect3  
                     city1                    city2                   city3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. cond1.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as s1] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s1] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s1]
2. cond1.2  [dropwown(1,2,3) as s2] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s2] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s2]
3. cond1.3  [dropwown(1,2,3) as s3] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s3] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s3]

4. cond2.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as s4] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s4] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s4]
5. cond2.2  [dropwown(1,2,3) as s5] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s5] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s5]

6. cond3.1  [dropwown(1,2,3) as s6] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s6] | [dropwown(1,2,3) as s6]
```

i learn from this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table
without getting understand how it does.

please help me.

here are my output html:

```
aspect1
<select style="width: 50px" name="Evaluation[1][k1]" id="Evaluation_1_k1">
.
.
.
<select style="width: 50px" name="Evaluation[7][k1]" id="Evaluation_7_k1">

aspect2
<select style="width: 50px" name="Evaluation[1][e1]" id="Evaluation_1_e1">
.
.
.
<select style="width: 50px" name="Evaluation[5][e1]" id="Evaluation_5_e1">

aspect3
<select style="width: 50px" name="Evaluation[1][s1]" id="Evaluation_1_s1">
.
.
.
<select style="width: 50px" name="Evaluation[6][s1]" id="Evaluation_6_s1">
```

in my _form i'm not using foreach statement, im using standard looping to generate those html code.
and in my controller still using the same as gii generated.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: i'm stuck in insert and update section. thanks Antoan M for your response. Is my code right to store array model, like: Evaluation[1][s1]?

Comment: So far you showed us only the code that take care of the user input. This looks OK as long as there are no `<select>` elements with same `name="..."` attribute. However there is no code that shows what you are doing with the client input, so there is no way for us to know if this code is working or not.